# ASP.NET MVC performance has suddenly become very slow

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, performance, windows-vista, s#arp-architecture

I'm using Billy McCafferty's rather excellent [S#arp Architecture](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/).  Everything was spiffing and running very quickly.

I then updated to the the latest ASP.NET MVC RC.  This meant I had to get the latest trunk of S#arp.

Also, two weeks ago, I updated from XP to Vista (32 bit)

My problem is that the performance has suddenly become woeful.

Everything seems to work, however it's become really slow.  Each http request is taking 1 second. Yes, one metric second - which you can imagine is making the page load like the webserver is being powered by an arthritic donkey in a giant, hastily constructed mouse wheel.

Every script or image on the page adds one second to the loading time.

- I don't have log4net turned on so I don't think it's that.
- This is running on the homepage so there's only a very minimal database stuff going on (which is very quick anyway)
- This is happening for simple images too, so I think it's got to be something at the routing or webserver level.

Any ideas what else it could be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is just a guess but i've seen slowness coming from having IPv6 enabled especially when using Firefox on localhost.

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/06/17/fixing-firefox-slowness-with-localhost-on-vista.aspx

Comment: This applies to Google Chrome as well. Browsing http://127.0.0.1/ instead of http://localhost/ is significantly faster.

Answer (score 4):

You could download dotTrace and profile your site.

I had a similar issue a few weeks ago and this application allowed me to get to the bottom of it in minutes.

Download the trial and give it a shot.

http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

Highly recommended!

Dave the Ninja

Comment: I thought of that, but wasn't sure it will help.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yeh, my app was taking around 16 seconds to start up and about 6 seconds per page there after.  dotTrace found the bug was in a third party assembly pretty much straight away.  As soon as I removed the assembly the app started flying again.  Download the trial and give it s shot.

Comment: It was the IP6 stuff but I'm still going to try dotTrace as frankly anything that JetBrains does rocks.

Comment: dotTrace found the problem I was having with MvcSiteMap in about 2 minutes. Simply amazing. Thx for the suggestion.

Comment: I tried running dottrace but couldn't make any sense of it. how do I know what's causing it to lag?